# Exporting angular material while bundling - using manfredsteyer/ngx-build-plus

Tags: angular, webpack, angular-material

I want to exclude @angular/material while building an angular7 application, as it's increasing the bundle size. Below is the snippet where other packages are being exported inside webpack.externals.js

```
module.exports = {
    "externals": {
        "rxjs": "rxjs",
        "@angular/core": "ng.core",
        "@angular/common": "ng.common",
        "@angular/platform-browser": "ng.platformBrowser",
        "@angular/elements": "ng.elements"
    }
}
```